# C# BigInteger with 2048bits

Tags: c#, rsa, biginteger

I'm creating a C# console application in order to find prime numbers and use them for RSA coding. Unfortunately latest standards (about the coding keys) are about 2048 bits. I tried with biginteger, but the maximum value I could calculate was 2^1023. It is possible to use larger numbers?

Comment: Take a look here: you can use decimal, etc.: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37907/how-long-is-a-2048-bit-rsa-key

Comment: Thank you J. McCabe, this can help me with my future applications. But the only problem is using 2048-bit long numbers on a C# application.

Comment: Why was the maximum value 2^1023? Show your code if you want help.

Comment: BigInteger big = new BigInteger(Math.Pow(2, 1023));
Console.WriteLine(big); //Trying with a bigger number would create an overflow @JamesKPolk

Comment: This answer might shed some light: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116252/how-does-rsacryptoserviceprovider-generate-keys - looks like the way to go is creating random bye arrays and doing that until u find one that represents a prime

Comment: No one else said it, so I will: Writing your own crypto code is dangerous. You'll get it wrong.  Everyone else has (but they've had a chance already to learn from their mistakes and harden their code). Algorithms are easy. Closing side channels is hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) has no upper limit (is limited only by available memory or maximum allocation size of it's underlaying byte array).

Your program throws exception because method Math.Pow(x,y) returns double and double cannot express 2^1024 or larger numbers.

To create larger numbers use this method instead

```
var big = BigInteger.Pow(2, 2048);
```

Alternatively use BigInteger constructor, that takes byte array or BigInteger.Parse() method.